# Sort through controls in UserForm with For Each structure. Error at the end of the sort

Tags: excel, vba, controls, userform

I have a simple UserForm with 6 text boxes. User enters info and clicks command button, and the point is to copy these inputs to a sheet. However, when I sort through the controls in the UF, I get an error towards the end and I can't figure out why. Here's a simplified version of my code (simple msgbox output):

```
Private Sub SetCD_Click()

    Dim ctrl As Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" And Not ctrl.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox ctrl.Value
            'Dim cell As Range
            'For Each cell In inputws.Range("F:F")
            '    If cell.Value = ctrl.Value Then cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = CDDate.Value
            'Next
        End If
    Next
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

MsgBox displaying accordingly, but once it sorts through the text boxes I get a 438: Object doesn't support this property or method. FYI, there are two lables (with no programming attached) and of course the confirmation/command button.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you hit the end of the data perhaps? You're going through *every cell* in Column F...  Also what is `CDDate.Value`?

Comment: @BruceWayne Hi Bruce, actually that part of the code is not running, just the ```MsgBox ctrl.Value``` and still get the error. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ```CCdate.value``` is the value in one of the text boxes in the UF, which I want to copy to the sheet. But again, this part is not running in this example. It's commented off.

Comment: At first I thought: if it sorts through ALL controls in the UF, eventually it will hit something like a Label, which would set off the error when it hits the ```If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" And Not ctrl.Value = "" Then``` line. However, I'm validating that the control is a text box, or not...

Comment: VBA doesn't short-circuit so `ctrl.Value = ""` is blowing up probably. Nest it as another `If`? You might also consider changing `Unload Me` (problematic) to `Me.Hide` (better).

Comment: @BigBen Yup, just tried it and it worked. Had to do another level of Ifs. And thanks for the heads up with ```me.hide```!!!

Comment: FWIW, I use `LEN(ctrl.Value)=0`, which I find to be more foolproof, too. That might work without nesting `IF`s.